# Deep copy of an object into List

Tags: c#, .net, deep-copy

I have a loop:

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
A obj = new A();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    obj.num = i; // Assigns the current i to the num attribute inside obj
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

However, in this case, whenever I modify `obj`, the previous instances of `obj` already added into the `list` will be modified. How do I write the code such that whatever that is added into the list has no more reference to the current value of `obj`?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with deep copying

Comment: There are **no** *previous instances* at all in your code. There's just *one*, which you keep overwriting.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a *new* `List<A>` via ***Linq*** instead of adding:

```
List<A> list = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 10)
  .Select(i => new A() { num = i })
  .ToList();
```

If you prefer adding

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  list.Add(new A() {num = i}); // <- Adding new (copied) instance
```

Comment: Was just about to post the exact same answer - only the indenting was different!

Answer (score 1):

you should move declaration of `obj` variable inside for loop

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    A obj = new A();
    obj.num = i; // Assigns the current i to the num attribute inside obj
    list.Add(obj);
}
```

it is all just about variable scopes. here `obj` scope is inside a for loop iteration. if you want to use a variable between iterations you should define it out of for loop like the way you have declared `obj` before.

Comment: Thanks. But an additional question. What if I need the values of `obj` to persist with every iteration of the loop? For example if `obj.num` depends on the previous value of `obj`?

Comment: @JohnTan Well, they're all in the list, so you have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because **probably** `A obj = new A();` is a ByReference object. So whenever you're in the loop, it's also changing the object you added on the List.

What you can do is either

1. Create the object inside the loop and then add it.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
       A obj = new A(); // create here so it's a new object always
       obj.num = i; // Assigns the current i to the num attribute inside obj
       list.Add(obj);
   }
   ```
2. Make the `A` type `IClonable`

   ```
   class A : ICloneable
   {
       public object Clone()
       {
           return this.MemberwiseClone();
       }
   }
   ```

and then just cast in before adding.

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
A obj = new A();
obj.num = 0;

for (int i = obj.num; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var clonedObj = obj.Clone() as A; // cast to be able to add in the collection
    clonedObj.num = i;
    list.Add(clonedObj);
}
```

Comment: @OndrejTucny yah, was in a meeting when i did the code so i didn't have that much time to think. Well the `(2)` just tackles the `"Deep Copy"` he wants